# Injecting property defaults into 3rd party Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a datepicker component in my project. Basic usage would be like this:

```
date-picker(language="fr" v-model="date")
```

There are several attributes which will get repeated each time we need to use a date picker: `language` for instance.

So I would like to be able to simply do that when a date picker is needed.

```
date-picker(v-model="date")
```

And that would default to `fr` for the `language` property of the 3rd party library.

Here is what I have tried:

- A custom component which extends the Datepicket component: Not that great as I need to define a template which contains the original date picker component. That translates to a superfluous wrapper component
- A plugin? I can only inject properties to the global Vue instance. (pretty new to Vue)
- Mixin does not apply as I would need to change the 3rd party component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you extended the component. But this should be elegant enough?

for e.g.

```
Vue.component("extended-datepicker", {
  extends: vuejsDatepicker,
  props: {
    format: {
      default: "yyyy MMM(MM) dd"
    },
    language: {
        default: fr
    }
  }
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/5917nqv8/2/

---

**Update** for the problem where "single file components are required to provide a template tag"

A Vue component is essentially a JavaScript object with certain properties.

You don't always need to use `.vue` single file component. In this case, you can just create a `.js` file that export an object.

For e.g. this `ExtendedDatepicker.js` would be a valid Vue component

```
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker";

export default {
  extends: Datepicker,
  props: {
    format: {
      default: "yyyy MMM(MM) dd"
    }
  }
};
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/9kn29053r

Comment: I was creating a single file component with that very same code. However it seems that single file components are required to provide a template tag. Even if they extend another component :/

Comment: @VincentMimoun-Prat I've updated the answer. It should help